# How to remove words from a sentence that carry no positive or negative sentiment?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

Im trying a sentiment analysis based approach on youtube comments, but the comments many times have words like mrbeast, tiger/'s, lion/'s, pewdiepie, james, etc which do not add any feeling in the sentence. I've gone through nltk's average_perception_tagger but it didn't work well as it gave the results as

my input:

```
"mrbeast james lion tigers bad sad clickbait fight nice good"
```

words that i need in my sentence:

```
"bad sad clickbait fight nice good"
```

what i got using average_perception_tagger:

```
[('mrbeast', 'NN'),
 ('james', 'NNS'),
 ('lion', 'JJ'),
 ('tigers', 'NNS'),
 ('bad', 'JJ'),
 ('sad', 'JJ'),
 ('clickbait', 'NN'),
 ('fight', 'NN'),
 ('nice', 'RB'),
 ('good', 'JJ')]
```

so as you can see if i remove mrbeast i.e NN the words like clickbait, fight will also get removed which than ultimately remove expressions from that sentence.

Comment: I am no expert in the literature. But being a sentimental word is a relative concept, I believe. For example, some words like tigers might make me feel fear, while not some others. I think it would be best to provide more details about sentimental expressions.

Comment: what is the actual question please ?  Please provide an example of the output that you are seeking.

Comment: See what im trying to do is classify youtube videos as good or bad depending on the user comments, so its obvious that words like good, fight, clickbait, wrong, amazing, no, not, etc are the one's that would help us to do so. However words like mrbeast, james, lion would only add noise to our model. My ultimate goal is to give every youtube video a rating which will be based on user comments on that video. I'm a beginner so please correct me if im going the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways of doing this like

1. you can create a set of positive and negative words and for each word in your grammar you can check if it exists in your set, if it does you should keep the word, else delete it. This however would first require all positive and negative words dataset.
2. you can use something like textblob which can give you the sentiment score of a word or a sentence. so with a cutoff sentiment score you can filter out the words that you don't need.

Answer (score 0):

okay,   this is what i do for companies that report on the LSE. You can do similar with your words.

```
# define what you consider to be positive, negative or neutral keywords
posKeyWords = ['profit', 'increase', 'pleased', 'excellent', 'good', 'solid financial', 'robust', 'significantly improved', 'improve']
negKeyWords = ['loss', 'decrease', 'dissapoint', 'poor', 'bad','decline', 'negative', 'bad', 'weather', 'covid' ]
neutralKeyWords = ['financial']
keyWords = posKeyWords + neutralKeyWords + negKeyWords
```

Next you get data as text (from whatever source you choose). Put the data (words) into a list (array).

```
dataTest = []
dataText = resp.text # or whatever source you are reading from
```

Mine is a response from a web query, but yours cour be from a text file or ther source.

Next create an empty dictionary to count key words into a dict (hashing is fast).

```
keyWordSummary = {} # dictionary of keywords & values
```

Finally, loop through the keywords and put them into the dict.

```
# look for some keywords
for kw in keyWords:
    kwVal = re.findall(kw, dataText)
    #print('keyword count:', kw, len(kwVal))
    # put into a dict
    keyWordSummary[kw] = len(kwVal)
```

You now have a list of word frequencies which you could analyse in a dataframe for example (which outside the scope of this particular question).

Comment: see there can be tens of thousands of words that can add feeling to a sentence like bad, sad, fight, mad, fu##, ......  How would i get a list of those predefined words, isn't there any other way instead of creating a list manually ?

Comment: there might be pre-set libraries that contain such, but you are now moving into the field of a persons interpretation of the english language. However, i am not aware of those and the dictionary would need to be very large (all possible words in the dictionary).